# Syntax Highlight e TinyMCE4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce-4

Sempre que coloco um script JS, PHP ou CSS no tinymce dentro das tags `<pre>`, como manda o Syntax Highlight, funciona perfeitamente, porém se quero um script HTML, como o tinymce é um editor de HTML ele retira a minha tag `<pre>` e joga o HTML para fora. Desse modo o Syntax Highlight não consegue ler e formatar o script. Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O TinyMCE, assim como todos os editores de textos para campos em página web eles convertem as tags, <tag>, em  caracteres especiais para que seja exibido em uma página HTML.

Por exemplo, se você entra no campo com o seguinte:

```
<pre>
     <div>
          Conteúdo da Div
     </div>
</pre>
```

O resultado desse campo será:

```
&lt;pre&gt;
     &lt;div&gt;
          Conteúdo da Div
     &lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/pre&gt;
```

Com isso, se você quer exibir com o Syntax Highlight, você teria (ou por linguagem PHP, ou JavaScript ou qualquer outra que desejar) setar o texto dentro de uma tag <pre>, dessa forma ficaria:

```
<pre>
     &lt;pre&gt;
          &lt;div&gt;
               Conteúdo da Div
          &lt;/div&gt;
     &lt;/pre&gt;
</pre>
```